# Gulp unexpectedly terminates, re-run works

Tags: windows, gulp

I got problems with `gulp` on the command-line when running tasks with dependencies (in-sequence and parallel). This might be specific to my environment, I need help were to look or how to make it any more verbose.

What happens:
I run `gulp bundle`
It starts:

```
Starting 'build'
Starting 'unbundle'
Finished 'unbundle' after 11ms
Starting 'clean'
```

Then I am back on my command prompt. No error message, the exit code was even `0`.

Then I run it again: `gulp bundle`

```
Starting 'build'
Starting 'unbundle'
Finished 'unbundle'
Starting 'clean'
Finished 'clean'
Starting 'build-system'
Starting 'build-html'
Starting 'build-css'
Starting 'build-style'
Starting 'build-locales'
Finished 'build-css'
Finished 'build-locales'
Finished 'build-style'
Finished 'build-html'
Finished 'build-system'
Finished 'build'
Starting 'bundle'
Finished 'bundle'
```

This time it worked. We I want to do `gulp bundle` again I have to run it twice again.

There are other tasks which involve even more dependencies where I must enter the same command **4x** before it works.

Everytime exit code 0. Even with flag `-LLLL` I do not get anything out of it. Gulp version is 3.9.1.

---

I have collected all affected tasks from the different files and combined their requires.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var paths = require('../paths');
var assign = Object.assign || require('object.assign');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var typescript = require('gulp-tsb');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var print = require('gulp-print');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var vinylPaths = require('vinyl-paths');
var del = require('del');
var bundler = require('aurelia-bundler');
var bundles = require('../bundles.js');

var sassOptions = {
    outputStyle: 'expanded'
};

var autoPrefixerOptions = {
    browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 1%']
};

var typescriptCompiler = typescriptCompiler || null;

gulp.task('build-system', function() {
  if(!typescriptCompiler) {
    typescriptCompiler = typescript.create(require('../../tsconfig.json').compilerOptions);
  }
  return gulp.src(paths.dtsSrc.concat(paths.source))
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(typescriptCompiler())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '/src'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output));
});

gulp.task('build-html', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.html)
    .pipe(changed(paths.output, {extension: '.html'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output));
});

gulp.task('build-css', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.css)
    .pipe(changed(paths.output, {extension: '.css'}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output));
});

gulp.task('build-style', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.style)
        .pipe(changed(paths.outputStyle, { extension: '.css' }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.outputStyle));
});

gulp.task('build-locales', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.locales)
        .pipe(changed(paths.output, { extension: '.json' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output));
});

gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  return runSequence(
    'clean',
    ['build-system', 'build-html', 'build-css', 'build-style', 'build-locales'],
    callback
  );
});

gulp.task('clean', ['unbundle'], function() {
  return gulp.src([paths.output])
    .pipe(vinylPaths(del));
});

var config = {
  force: true,
  baseURL: './wwwroot',
  configPath: './wwwroot/config.js',
  bundles: bundles.bundles
};

gulp.task('bundle', ['build'], function() {
  return bundler.bundle(config);
});

gulp.task('unbundle', function() {
  return bundler.unbundle(config);
});
```

Every task returns a gulp pipe, a Promise of call the callback method.

I have no idea why this happens and why calling gulp multiple times solves the problem once (and then you must call it multiple times again).

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @Barryman9000 The gulp task code is split accross several files but I collected all tasks which are part of the example and updated the question with the code.

Comment: In your first screen shot, does the "clean" task ever show as finished? Try moving "unbundle" into runSequence in the "build" task rather than running it as a dependency with "clean."

Comment: @Barryman9000 Unfortunately the "clean" task never shows as finished, I am just dropped back to the command line. Also moving unbundle into the runSequence rather than having it as dependency did not change anything.

Comment: Why is the src in the clean task wrapped in brackets but not wrapped in other tasks? I'm not sure what vinylPaths(del) does but something in your clean task seems o be causing this. If you don't call clean does everything work?

Comment: @Barryman9000 You were right, there is a problem with the `clean` task. Maybe because the pipe had no gulp.dest? The sample https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/delete-files-folder.md shows a gulp.dest although there is nothing to place. I exchanged it with a simple module call to del (which returns a Promise) and it works!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. I've always just used `del` for cleaning resources which just takes an array, there's no piping, no dest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To have the question documented with its answer:*

The problem was a breakage in the pipe model with the `clean` task.

I solved it using another approach, here simply calling `del` which returns a Promise (which is returned).

```
gulp.task('clean', ['unbundle'], function() {
  return del([paths.output]);
});
```